# Ubuntu Installation on HTC Salsa

Tags: ubuntu-touch, htc

I was trying to install Ubuntu for smartphone on HTC Salsa.
In the final step I got the following error.

```
~$ sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
2014/08/18 22:54:19 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2014/08/18 22:54:19 Device is |icon_g|
2014/08/18 22:54:19 Device icon_g not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel devel
```

Please guide me. I followed http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Answer (score 1):

The HTC Salsa is NOT supported. The officially supported development devices are only the Nexus 4, 7 (WiFi) and 10 from Google. The instructions you posted will NOT work with any non-supported devices.

A wider set of devices is supported by community-driven ports but I see no support for the HTC Salsa there. [See here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) for the list.

The status page for each device in there gives instructions on how to install, though again, ubuntu-device-flash can't help you and you would need to follow a device-specific installation process.

Comment: agree with you.I thought of giving it a shot if it works.Let me know if there is anyway to play around and make it work